# Not able to bind UserControl from main View

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, user-controls, prism-4

I have created user control which contain TextBox and PasswordBox.
**RestrictedBox.xaml**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisConverter" />
        <Converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisConverterReverse" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="Auto">
        <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,5">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding TextValue}" Visibility="{Binding IsTextBox,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverter}}" BorderBrush="Green" />
            <PasswordBox Password="{Binding TextValue}" Visibility="{Binding IsTextBox,Converter={StaticResource boolToVisConverterReverse}}" BorderBrush="Red" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

**RestrictedBox.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class RestrictedBox : UserControl
    {
        public RestrictedBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string TextValue
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextValueProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TextValue", typeof(string), typeof(RestrictedBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

        public bool IsTextBox
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsTextBoxProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsTextBoxProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTextBoxProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsTextBox", typeof(bool), typeof(RestrictedBox), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool)));
    }
```

Now i added above User Control to my **LoginView.xaml** page

```
<control:RestrictedBox TextValue="Imdadhusen" IsTextBox="True"   />
```

**Now i run the application but the TextValue = "Imdadhusen" is not bind with my text box and the second property IsTextBox is set to True that means it will automatically hide Passwordbox else Textbox.**

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*UserControls do not register themselves as the data context automatically so the binding inside the user control won't have anything to bind to.*

**I have added following line my UserControl codebehind to enable default binding.**

```
public RestrictedBox()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     this.DataContext = this;
}
```

Thanks,
Imdadhusen

Answer (score 2):

Please set your DataContext because in user control it does not understand DataContext.
So try to this in your constructor.

```
 this.DataContext = this;
```

May be this help to you...